# Структура таблиц в бд

Tags: mysql

Помогите доработать структуру таблиц.Задача следующая есть юзеры и есть премиум юзеры.Для премиум юзеров есть пакеты,которые в свою очередь содержат определенные опции.Есть кастомный пакет в котором можно указывать для каждой опции свою цену. Какие таблицы создать для хранения цен для каждой опции.На данный момент у меня структура следующая.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вполне можно добавить более общий тэг sql, вопрос не содержит узкоспецифичных деталей - и это увеличит аудиторию просматривающих вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Фактически, у вас есть два вида тарифных планов: с фиксированной ценой и ценой, которая рассчитывается по подключенным опциям.

Конкретную структуру таблиц рекомендовать сложно, потому что она зависит от бизнес-логики и того, какие запросы нужно будет выполнять, какие чаще и т.п.

Но попробую.

Нижеописанная структура будет исходить из предположения, что есть таблица тарифных планов (tariffs) и таблица опций тарифных планов (tariff_options).
Цена тарифа будет считаться как сумма всех опций тарифных планов, в явном виде цены как поля на tariffs не будет.

Для простых тарифов нужно будет заводить одну запись в таблице опций, для составных - несколько возможных.

Естесственно, что понадобятся ещё таблицы - подключенные тарифы где будет внешний ключ на пользователей и подключенные опции.

Далее я предлагаю вам самому продумать детали в зависимости от вашего решения - вы их лучше представляете, чем мы. Например, реализация премиум-аккаунтов могла быть всего лишь булевским полем на таблице пользователей, а могла бы содержать даты начала и конца премиум-тарифа. Почему у вас сделано по-другому -- из краткого описания непонятно, но явно была какая-то логика.

PS И названия сущностей - мои не совсем "бьются" с вашей предметной областью. У вас термины "пользователь", "преиум-пользователь", "пакет для премиум-пользователя", "опция пакета"; я вместо пакетов говорил о "тарифных планах", подразумевая, что у любого пользователя есть тарифный план. В качестве концепта это ещё прокатит, а когда реальное приложение -- лучше когда названия сущностей (таблиц, переменных) соотносится с терминами автоматизируемой области.

Comment: .это... а можно хранить в тбл булевское значение? Какой размер поля для "буля"? ИЛИ в некоторых тбл можно хранить, а в некоторых нельзя? Спрошу ка я у гуголя...

Comment: Изначально так и было в таблице users хранил is_pro_user, но потом всетаки решил хранить там ссылку на про юзера из таблицы pro_users

Comment: @quaresma89 поэтому я и говорю, что конкретных решений лучше не давать, а вам самому посмотреть, что под ваш случай больше подходит.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy Можно. В MySQL есть специальный тип поля Bool (Boolean). Есть и альтернативы - TinyInt(1) и Enum..

Comment: интересовало именно BOOL. Спрашивал потому что в той программе в которой я редактирую тбл нет булевского типа. ААА НЕТ!  Кажись есть - называется bit. Как же я протупил... :(( та нет это не оно. короче говоря меня спасет только ссылка на офф доки по типам данных. Я еще не искал. вот скрин - можно установить длину поля в 1. это и будет булев тип http://itmages.ru/image/view/4542034/3a422172 , но прямого указания что это именно bool я не вижу.

Comment: вот http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html вечером  почитаю.